# Submit button to write on another table

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create a form by VBA. Therefore, I'm using buttons to collect information and then, when clicking in the submit button, It should write the answers on another sheet, in a specific table. The next time you will use it and submit, the excel should add an extra line.

I have wrote a code but instead of starting to write the answers on the 1st line of the table (Cell B7), it starts at the end of it (B544). Do you have any idea why?

Links to the problem:

[image: The end of the table]

[image: The beginning of the table]

[image: VBA Code]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please do not post pictures of code. Instead, include the code itself so people can copy/paste it if they want to.

Comment: Thank you for the help, I will use this tips next time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are counting the table rows to use that number for the `position` parameter in the `Add()` method of `ListRows` object, I suppose you want to add a new row at the bottom of the table

To add a new row at the bottom of a `ListObject` object, just omit the `position` parameter

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim row As ListRow

    Set row = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Teste-Base de dados").ListObjects("Table1").ListRows.Add
        row.Range(1) = ...
        row.Range(2) = ...

        ...

End Sub
```

which you can also "reduce" to:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
       
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Teste-Base de dados").ListObjects("Table1").ListRows.Add
        .Range(1) = ...
        .Range(2) = ...
    End With

    ...

End Sub
```

While if you want to add the new row as the first one, then use `1` for the `position` parameter

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim row As ListRow

    Set row = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Teste-Base de dados").ListObjects("Table1").ListRows.Add(1)
        row.Range(1) = ...
        row.Range(2) = ...

        ...

End Sub
```

or its "collapsed" twin

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Teste-Base de dados").ListObjects("Table1").ListRows.Add(1)
        .Range(1) = ...
        .Range(2) = ...
    End With
    
    ...
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Hello! Thanks for the help, the second approach worked for me.

However, I would like to know how can I add new rows one after another (if the first row has values, it should add values to the 2nd row, and so on)

For example, the first approach will add new rows at the end of the table, no matter if it has values or not (the table could be empty) -  "ListRows.Add"

On the second approach, one row will be added on the 1st position, while the remaining rows will go down (to the 2nd, 3rd, 4th,.... row) - "ListRows.Add(1)"

Thank you

Comment: Hi @kitsch05. Glad it worked. You may then want to mark the answer as accepted, since it solves your posted question. While, as per this site rules, please post a new question for the new answer

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help, this approach worked for me:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim row As ListRow

    Set row = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Teste-Base de dados").ListObjects("Table1").ListRows.Add(1)
        row.Range(1) = ...
        row.Range(2) = ...

        ...

End Sub
```

However, I would like to know how can I add new rows one after another (if the first row has values, it should add values to the 2nd row, and so on).

For example, this first approach will add new rows at the end of the table, no matter if it has values or not (the table could be empty):

```
 Dim row As ListRow

    Set row = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Teste-Base de dados").ListObjects("Table1").ListRows.Add
```

On the second approach, one row will be added on the 1st position, while the remaining rows will go down (to the 2nd, 3rd, 4th,.... row):

```
Dim row As ListRow

    Set row = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Teste-Base de dados").ListObjects("Table1").ListRows.Add(1)
```